# Newly added space on Ubuntu Partition showing as Unused

Tags: ubuntu, partition, cryptsetup

I've a Ubuntu OS running as a VMWare virtual machine. It was setup with 30 GB of space, but I am running out, so I extended the disk to 40 GB in VMWare, and then extended the partition by booting into gparted. After booting back into my OS, I see the partition is now more voluminous,
[image]
[image]
but still not seeing that space available
[image]

I don't know if this is related, but the disk is encrypted. How can I get this additional 10 GB of newly-added space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That *unused* space just means that it's empty, that files have not yet been written to it; that is the expected behavior.

But you have LVM partitions, so in order to fill that space you need to perform an ***lvextend***. Something like:

```bsh
pvresize /dev/sda2
lvextend -l+100%FREE /dev/mapper/cryptdata
resize2fs  /dev/mapper/cryptdata
```

Get detailed [info here](https://blog.vbonhomme.fr/extend-a-lvm-partition-after-increasing-its-virtual-disk-on-virtualbox/).